# Вывести содержимое массива в textbox wpf

Tags: c#, массивы, wpf, textbox

Допустим я ищу файлы формата txt в определенной папке и вывожу в массив, но у меня это не получается, делаю это так:

```
string x = tb2.Text;
string[] file = Directory.GetFiles(x, ".txt");
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
tb3.Text += file[i];
```

Comment: (1) А вы уверены, что у вас что-то находится? Паттерн `".txt"` выглядит неправильно. (2) А почему цикл до 100?

Comment: Похоже он пуст, проверил file.Length.ToString() -  выдало 0

Comment: Вот, точно вместо точки звезда

Comment: Заменил, снова проверяю   file.Length, результат правильный 3 файла тхт в папке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, вам нужно что-то такое:

```
tb3.Text = string.Join("\n", Directory.GetFiles(tb2.Text, "*.txt"));
```

Comment: Ваш способ работает, но я такого не знаю. Сделал через цикл, почему компилятор выдавал ошибку когда я явно указывал до какого элемента считать, то самое число 100?

Comment: То есть я проверяю сколько нашлось файлов через file.Length внося в переменную число найденных файлов txt (int g = file.Length;), и затем подставляю в счетчик цикла  for(int i = 0; i < g; ++i)

Comment: @SOFL: Куда ж ему деваться, работает :) С указанием точной длины неправильно потому, что вы не знаете заранее, сколько элементов будет в массиве. Подумайте, что случится, если их всего 3, а вы обращаетесь к индексу 99.

Comment: Спасибо, понял. Такого индекса не будет существовать результат - ошибка. Просто в моем понимании он дойдя до предела равного трем должен был сам выйти из цикла и все)

Comment: @SOFL: Не, он не такой умный, он делает то, что вы ему сказали.